# Can you use the address of a constexpr variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, constexpr, memory-address

I have a variable whose address is passed as the fourth parameter to [setsocketopt](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsockopt.html). Notice that this parameter is declared as a constant pointer (`const void *optval`).

In a patch I put up for review I changed the declaration of that variable to static constexpr. A reviewer of this change had concerns: he felt that it was questionable whether you can always take the address of a constexpr. He suggests that I make it const. I couldn't find much about addresses of constexpr variables and concerns about it after googling around. Can someone explain what the guarantees are concerning the address of a constexpr variable and what the caveats are about using it (if any)?

In case it's helpful, here's the code (I added `static constexpr`, it was just an `int` before):

```
static constexpr int ONE = 1;
setsockopt(socket_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &ONE, sizeof(ONE));
```

Thanks!

Comment: All `constexpr` does is inform the compiler it is able to evaluate the **value** of the function or variable at compile time. It does not change the fact that `ONE` is in this case refers to an lvalue which you can certainly take its address. In other words, it does not change the lifetime of your variable, if that's what you (or your colleague) are concerned about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every object is guaranteed to have an address per [[intro.object]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#8)

> An object has **nonzero size if** it
>
> - is not a potentially-overlapping subobject, or
> - **is not of class type**, or
> - is of a class type with virtual member functions or virtual base classes, or
> - has subobjects of nonzero size or bit-fields of nonzero length.
>
> Otherwise, if the object is a base class subobject of a standard-layout class type with no non-static data members, it has zero size. Otherwise, the circumstances under which the object has zero size are implementation-defined. **Unless it is a bit-field, an object with nonzero size shall occupy one or more bytes of storage**, including every byte that is occupied in full or in part by any of its subobjects. An object of trivially copyable or standard-layout type ([basic.types]) shall occupy contiguous bytes of storage.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Since `ONE` is a non-class-non-bit-field type, it's in storage and you can take its address.

Comment: A bit-field is an object and occupies a region of storage, but does not have an address. See [intro.object]/8.

Comment: @aschepler Good point.  I've updated the quote as that works even better.

Comment: Oops, I meant C++17 [\[intro.object\]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#8), which is paragraph 9 in today's LaTeX sources.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can take the address of any object which is not a non-type non-reference template parameter or a bit-field. A variable declared `constexpr` (or one which is implicitly a constant expression) can be used in more contexts, not fewer.

It's true that the compiler can often avoid using any memory storage for a `constexpr` variable *if it's not needed*. But if the address is taken, that will probably require the memory storage, so the compiler will need to treat it more like an ordinary object in that case.